# How to get an image form field to update only if a new file has been chosen in django?

Tags: django, forms, file-upload

I have a custom profile form with an image field where users can upload a profile picture along with some other fields. It works fine so far. The problem is, when submitting the form, it always uploads and updates the field, even when a user didn't choose a file. So a user has submitted the form and uploaded a picture. He/she then comes back at a later point to update some other field, but not the picture. After submitting the form the profile pic is gone and has resetted to default. How do I get the image field to update only if a new file has been chosen?

modesl.py

```
class Profil(models.Model):
    def content_file_userpic(instance, filename):
        return '/'.join(['pics', instance.user.username, filename])

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    user_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=content_file_userpic, blank=True, verbose_name='Foto', default='user_pic_default.png')
```

forms.py

```
class ProfilForm(ModelForm):
    user_pic = forms.ImageField(label='Foto',required=False, widget=forms.FileInput)
```

Comment: Show your view code, please.

Comment: def profil_edit(request):
 try:
  form  = ProfilForm(instance=Profil.objects.get(pk=request.user))
  context = {"profil_formular": form}
  template = "profil/edit.html"
 except ObjectDoesNotExist:
  print("The entry doesn't exist.")
  return redirect("profil_add")
 if request.method == "POST":
  form = ProfilForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
  if form.is_valid():
   profil = form.save(commit=False)
   profil.user = request.user
   profil.bewerbungsnr = request.user.id
   profil.save()
   info(request, ("profile updated"))
   return redirect('/profil')
 return render(request, template, context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `instance` argument to the form constructor:

```
profile = Profil.objects.get(user=request.user)
form = ProfilForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
```